# How do I set the status to "Off Work" for Skype for Business API?

Tags: skype-for-business

All the other statuses can be updated. But I am not understanding on what to pass if it is a "Off - Work" scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Off Work" presence state is a actually the "Away" presence state with a activity id set to "off-work".  The "activity" has a bunch of Custom Token's setup for each language that is installed so it displays correctly text for the current system setup. e.g. "Off Work" in English.

**UCMA:**

You can reproduce this yourself or you can use the pre-created PresenceState.UserOffWork value.

e.g.

```
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
    endpoint.PresenceServices.BeginUpdatePresenceState, 
    endpoint.PresenceServices.EndUpdatePresenceState,
    PresenceState.UserOffWork, 
    null);
```

The above example is assuming you are using a UCMA UserEndpoint (endpoint).

**Lync Client SDK:**

For the Lync Client SDK you need to publish an Away presence type with the activity id of "off-work":

```
    var publishData = new Dictionary<PublishableContactInformationType, object>
    {
        {PublishableContactInformationType.Availability, ContactAvailability.Away},
        {PublishableContactInformationType.ActivityId, "off-work"}
    };
    Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.Self.BeginPublishContactInformation,
                           client.Self.EndPublishContactInformation,
                           publishData,
                           null);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But what do I need to pass if I want to change the status from 'OffWork' to 'Away'. Passing Away is not updating the presence.

Comment: That is simple, for UCMA use PresenceState.UserAway. For Lync Client SDK, drop the "off-work" line, i.e. you don't have a ActivityId for the Away availability.